# Missing options from Manage blade from Azure Enterprise Applications

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ffV1.jpg)Two of Azure Enterprise applications were showing below options till yesterday night under Manage blade:

**Properties, Owners, Users and Groups, Provisioning, Application Proxy and Self-Service.**

But, today I am seeing only three options, rest are missing: **Properties, Owners and Provisioning**
In the absence of Users and Groups, the owner of the applications can't add users or groups to this application.

In spite of having global admin access I can't see those missing options, The owner of these two Enterprise Applications also can't see those missing options.

None, of the MS article, talks about this issue, can someone please help how to get those options back.

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine on my side. If you did nothing and the buttons disappeared, you need to raise a support ticket on Azure portal by following [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

[image]